# Finding changes in MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, database-design, mongodb

I'm designing a MongoDB database that works with a script that periodically polls a resource and gets back a response which is stored in the database. Right now my database has one collection with four fields , **id**, **name**,  **timestamp** and **data**.

I need to be able to find out which names had changes in the data field between script runs, and which did not.
In pseudocode,

```
if(data[name][timestamp]==data[name][timestamp+1]) //data has not changed
store data in collection 1
else //data has changed between script runs for this name
store data in collection 2
```

Is there a query that can do this without iterating and running javascript over each item in the collection? There are millions of documents, so this would be pretty slow.

Should I create a new collection named **timestamp** for every time the script runs? Would that make it faster/more organized? Is there a better schema that could be used?

The script runs once a day so I won't run into a namespace limitation any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a neat question b/c the short is basically: **you will have to iterate and run javascript over each item**.

The part where this gets "neat" is that this isn't really different from what an SQL solution would have to do. I mean, you're basically joining a table to itself where `x.1=x.1` and `y.1=y.2`. Even if the relational DB can handle such a beast, it's definitely not going to be fast with millions of entries.

So the truth is, you're doing this right way. Here are the extra details I would use to make this cleaner.

1. Ensure that you have an index on Name/Timestamp.
2. Run a `db.mycollection.find().foreach()` across the data set.
3. Foreach entry you're going to **a)** Perform comparison. **b)** Save appropriately. **c)** Update a flag indicating that this record has been processed.
4. On future loads you should be able to add a query to your find. `db.mycollection.find({flag:{$exists:false}}).foreach()`
5. Use `db.eval()` to help with speed.

The reason for the "Name/Timestamp" index is that you're going to be looking up each "successor" by "Name/Timestamp", so you want to be quick here.

The reason for the "processed" flag is that you should never have to re-run the same item. If given timestamp 'n' you find 'n+1', then that's the only 'n+1' you're going to have.

Honestly, if you're only running this once / day, it's quite likely that the speed will be just fine, especially if you only running on new records. Just assume that it's going to take several minutes.